# Is it illegal for a private citizen of the US to own and operate an orbital kinetic weapons platform?

Tags: law, orbital, weapon

Let's say someone pays for the shipping through an as yet unnamed commercial launch company.  And they place something in orbit that is effectively a kinetic weapons platform.  Or at least has the capacity to operate as one while having an alternative primary function.

Ignoring the illegality of shipping a weapon to space, I know that's illegal.  But let's say this third party hands over control to another party.  Is the ownership of that platform, once it's in orbit, in and of itself illegal?

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems to be a loophole in WMD law. It would be illegal to use and illegal to give to a foreign party, but I cannot find anything saying that it is illegal to possess. If it were nuclear, it would be, but since it is kinetic--it seems to be a grey area. That said, you would probably still draw the attention of the FBI: https://www.fbi.gov/investigate/wmd. And I'm pretty sure a judge would not look favorably on you if you went to court over it.

Comment: To be fair, the SpaceX Falcon 9 has demonstrated 2-4 meter accuracy landing a first stage, 5 times now.  A 140 foot tall vehicle, on the order of 100,000 lbs, coming in on 100,000 lbs of thrust should really count as a kinetic weapons platform. I.e. Do NOT piss off Elon Musk, or 100,000 of angry thrust could land on your house/office. (Programming error, you know how it goes...)

Comment: Giving new meaning to the saying "Walk softly and carry a very loud, very big, and very heavy stick".

Comment: No, the US legal definition of WMD is ridiculously broad, and this unquestionably qualifies.

Comment: @geoffc You would have to demonstrate at least intent to use as a weapon to make it illegal, and I'm pretty sure there are a lot of eyes on SpaceX.

Comment: @RussellBorogove You misunderstand me, it qualifies as a WMD, but possession of a WMD (except nuclear or biological ones) is not illegal.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Unless possession can be construed as intent to use, but as geoffc pointed out, that *can* be a grey area.

Comment: This seems to be a question for https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Philipp Law may be able to answer this with greater fidelity, but space law *is* on topic here.

Comment: Why would you want to go to all the trouble of putting it in orbit? Getting things to deorbit requires energy and reaction mass, and it's difficult to do so accurately so as to hit a desired target. It would be *much* easier to launch your kinetic-energy weapon from the earth's surface  in a ground-to-ground trajectory. A satellite is also an extremely vulnerable object compared to a missile in a silo.

Comment: I thought that every launch to orbit, and thereby presumably every payload, needed to be approved by the government of whichever country you are a citizen of. So whether or not it is illegal, I doubt you'd get launch approval (..unless you're a citizen of a rogue nation, but even then, I doubt they'd want to piss off the international community by allowing their *citizens* to launch questionable payloads).

Comment: No. "The right to bear arms shall not be infringed." However that [won't stop the government from murdering you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNCbgJ55jQY).

Comment: First suggested (at least publicly) in Heinlien's scifi novel *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*. The US military (and I suspect, the Soviet military) obviously looked into kinetic weapons prior to that.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Sorry to be the SF trivia police, but ... Heinlein described the idea of orbital nuclear weapons in 1948 in his YA novel Space Cadet, and moon-based kinetic energy weapons in The Moon is a Harsh Mistress, 1966. He never described orbital kinetic energy weapons, and I would suspect that the reason was that they don't make sense, for the physics reasons I described in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 9):

The legal definition of "Weapon of Mass Destruction" in US law is quite broad (see https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/04/definition_of_w.html ), and an orbital kinetic weapon definitely qualifies if the projectile is big enough to re-enter in one piece. The FBI and/or ATF will want to have a talk with the owner.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: kinetic works around much the existing body of legislation cited here.  and specific intent in design as a weapon appears to be attached to all remaining specific classifications.  so a secondary unintentional function that would be capable of acting as a kinetic bombardment platform would potentially be legal?  Although use could demonstrate intent... ?

Comment: @MattJoyce Note that Russell did not say it would be illegal, just that the FBI would want to have a talk.

Comment: I don't have time for a deep dive here but at a glance I think the only thing they can really pin on the owner is an arms dealer charge, possession of unlicensed firearm.

Comment: Any practical kinetic weapon would have a bore greater than a half inch and/or propellant charge of more than four ounces, and there's a "device similar to any of the devices described in preceding clauses" catch-all.

Comment: The section covering missiles and rockets propellant will catch your orbital kinetic weapon given the fact that you will have to launch it into space in order for it to be of use. In addition, if this does not suffice, it will catch anything using conventional methods of propulsion to accelerate to dangerous speeds.

Comment: The formulation of the question excludes consideration of how the weapon platform got there.